different color result in principle bdsf
I have this material and i need to mix color ramp with principle bdsf. I notice that my color is different when i connect tio principle bdsf. I tried to change the value of saturation and roughness but it's still the same. Why is it different?



If you plug the ColorRamp directly into the Output it will act as if you've plugged the ColorRamp into an Emission shader, while if you plug it into a Principled BSDF it will act as if you plug it into a Diffuse mixed with other nodes like Specular, the lights and environment will reflect on the surface, therefore the difference.
